Problem based on Polynomials with indices
$\frac {2+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}} + \frac {2-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{3}}}$
This is the equation to be solved that I came across in a book. I tried by substituting
${2+ \sqrt{3}}$ as a and $2-\sqrt {3}$ as b. After cross multiplying and substituting $ a + b = 4 $ and $ab = 1$ ,I got $\frac {4\sqrt{2} - (\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})}{1+\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})}$ Now I am stuck here. What do I do?

https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%20%7B2%2B%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%20%2B%20%5Csqrt%7B2%20%2B%20%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%20%7B2-%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%20-%20%5Csqrt%7B2%20-%20%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%7D%24&p=1

By the way I'm curious to know what "Polynomials with indices" means.

$$(\sqrt3\pm1)^2=?$$

I am kinda beginner, so just don't judge me for my language. The expression has to be reduced in the simplest form. The answer is √2

Asking you to clarify confusing things about your post is not "judging you".  Neither is explaining to you what is wrong, and what you should have said instead. That is "educating", not "judging." It is how you learn to communicate clearly. There is no polynomial and no indices at all here, so your title is completely disconnected from your post. And an "equation" always has an "=" sign in it. What you have is an expression to be simplified, not an equation to be solved.`

If your question mean to simplify the equation then!
Let, $a=2+√3$, $b=2-√3$; So we have,
$a-b=2√3$, $ab=1$, $2a+2b-2=6$, $2b-1=3-2√3$, $1-2a=-3-2√3$, $(√a+√b)^2=6$ and
$(2-a)(2-b)=-3$;
Now, on substitution and simplification it becomes
$$\frac{a}{√2+√a}+ \frac{b}{√2-√b}$$
On rationalising, it turns to
$$\frac{a(√2-√a)}{2-a}+\frac{b(√2+√b)}{2-b}$$
which becomes
$$\frac{a(√2-√a)(2-b)+b(√2+√b)(2-a)}{-3}$$
On further simplification it becomes
$$\frac{√2(2a-2ab+2b) +√b(2b-ab) +√a(ab-2a)}{-3}$$
which turns to becomes
$$\frac{√2(2a+2b-2)+√b(2b-1)+√a(1-2a)}{-3}$$
which simplifies to
$$\frac{6√2+√b(3-2√3)+√a(-3-2√3)}{-3}$$
It again simplifies to
$$\frac{6√2+3(√b-√a)-2√3(√b+√a)}{-3}$$
which on rationalising further becomes
$$\frac{6√2(√a+√b)+3(b-a)-2√3(√b+√a)^2}{-3(√a+√b)}$$
It simplifies to
$$\frac{6√2(√a+√b)-18√3}{-3(√a+√b)}$$
further simplification results into
$$-2√2+\frac{6√3}{(√a+√b)}$$
And on rationalising it comes to
$$-2√2+3(√a-√b)$$
Hence, finally it simplifies to
$$3(√(2+√3)-√(2-√3))-2√2$$
Also, it is to notice that
$$√(2+√3)-√(2-√3)=√2$$
So, our final simplification results to,
$$√2$$
